# How to record macro to copy and paste table just by selecting starting cell in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to be able to record a macro which copies and pastes a small 3x2 table anywhere on the worksheet just by selecting the starting cell. This is the code from my attempt, but when I select a cell to run my macro the result is blank.

```
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1:B3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
        , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: What is stopping you to do that? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Automate-tasks-with-the-Macro-Recorder-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "Selecting the starting cell"? What is the starting cell in relation to the macro? Is this where we will copy? Is this where we will paste? Or do you mean to treat this cell like a button?

Comment: The starting cell is where we will paste. I have the table already made and I just want to be able to select a blank starting cell and run my macro so that the table pastes there.

Comment: `ActiveCell.Range("A1").Select` This means that it just copies back over itself. You didn't answer @urdearboy questions. Please re-read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to explain how the macro will be triggered, how the source range will be defined, and how the target range will be defined. An example would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a better route than relying on the `Active Cell`.
Prompt your user with a `Input Box` which allows them to select a desired cell.

This code also accounts for the possibility of the user hitting  <kbd>Cancel</kbd>

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copy_Table()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- UPDATE SHEET
Dim MyTable As Range, PasteRange As Range
Set MyTable = ws.Range("A1:B3")

On Error Resume Next
    Set PasteRange = Application.InputBox("Select Desired Location for Table", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not PasteRange Is Nothing Then
    PasteRange.Resize(3, 2).Value = MyTable.Value
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow this works! Thank you so much. Do you happen to know what I'd need to change to the code to allow for pasting with formats?